# EF Code First MetadataException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I've installed EF v5 via NuGet into a VS 2010 project. Here's the code:

```
public class HeliosCpDataContext : DbContext
{
    public HeliosCpDataContext() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.cn_HeliosCpNtAuth) {}
    public IEnumerable<Test> GetTests()
    {
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<Test>("EXEC App.Test");
    }
}

   public class Test
    {
       public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
       public int OrderId {get;set;}
    }

   CREATE PROC [dbo].[Test]
   AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON


SELECT TOP 10 OrderNumber, OrderId
FROM dbo.Orders o
```

Field [OrderNumber] is Varchar(20), [OrderId] is INT

Here's the app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HeliosCp.Data.Properties.Settings.cn_HeliosCpNtAuth"
      connectionString="Data Source=DCXVRSQ471;Initial Catalog=SCPT_HeliosCp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I try to execute:

```
  var context = new HeliosCp.Data.HeliosCpDataContext();
  var test = context.GetTests().FirstOrDefault();
```

I get a MetadataException "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(137,6) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type int.
(137,6) : error 0063: Scale facet isn't allowed for properties of type int."

I've tried explicitly casting each field in the sproc as Varchar & int, explicitly executing the query ("SELECT TOP 10 ...") via the SqlQuery function instead of the sproc, *removing* the query entirely from the sproc (i.e., leaving nothing in the body of the sproc), and I get the exact same Exception, every time. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it all the code you have in your project? Since the error is on 137th line of the edmx file it seems to me that you have more than this. Can you do EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx and post the line that has facets? Generating a model like this would be a bug in the EF.

Comment: I'm using codefirst, so there's no Edmx if I understand correctly

Comment: There is but you don't see it. That's why I asked you to use EdmxWriter. The exception you get is thrown when reading this generated edmx.

Comment: I get the same error upon execution of EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx

Comment: Can you file a bug at http://entityframework.codeplex.com/ and attach the repro?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening you edmx file and remove the precision attribute of your int